# slf4j upgrade binding update error ? incompatible binding

Tags: java, apache, logging, tomcat7, slf4j

I have a legacy java EE app that I am porting to the maven framework . the app initially used the slf4j 1.5x series for logging , I am upgrading to the 1.7.1 logger . I read on the slf4j site that

http://slf4j.org/faq.html#where_is_binding

> Please note that all bindings depend on slf4j-api.jar.

I upgraded my slf4j-api.jar to 1.7 and did with slf4j-simple and slf4j-log4j12 too . I still seem to be getting errors of an incompatible binding which is quite frankly driving me up an wall . Any help would be appreciated

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\adam\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ myWebApp\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar) - jar not loaded.
 See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Oct 14, 2013 1:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJar
File
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\adam\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ myWebApp\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Oct 14, 2013 1:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJar
File
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\adam\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ myWebApp\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5-6.1.11.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/adam/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/
myWebApp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl
/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/adam/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/
myWebApp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.5.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/
StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.

SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.

SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x.
```

Comment: This output is telling you exactly which files are the older versions.  Maybe you added the new files to your build but your web app deployment is still using the old (1.5.0) versions.

Comment: I suspect you are right , i am not sure on how this is happening as I changed all the dependencies to 1.7.1 , I may have to check the build

Comment: @user1801279 Your build may not have deleted the old copies from the `lib` directory. Run a full clean and check whether they show back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try upgrading to slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar , i had the same problem ,, it's working for me now.